# ¿Cómo utilizar un mismo fragment para varios tabs en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo varios Tabs (la cantidad exacta siempre varia porque son según la cantidad de categorías).

Este es mi fragment_categorias.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ec.com.distribuidoresluisgonzalez.CategoriasFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista_categorias_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,ObsoleteLayoutParam"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar_categorias"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Este es mi clase CategoriasFragment.java

```
public class CategoriasFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


public static CategoriasFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    CategoriasFragment fragment = new CategoriasFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public CategoriasFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSatate){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceSatate);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categorias, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Este es mi FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String id_categoria;
    private String [] id_categorias = null;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String id_categoria) {
        super(fm);
        this.id_categoria = id_categoria;
        this.id_categorias = obtenerIdCategorias(this.id_categoria, obtenerCantTabs(this.id_categoria));
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        llenarListaProductosCategorias("216");
        return CategoriasFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return obtenerCantTabs(this.id_categoria);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String [] nombres = obtenerNombresTabs(this.id_categoria, obtenerCantTabs(this.id_categoria));

        return nombres[position];
    }

    public int obtenerCantTabs(String id_categoria){
        int cantCategorias = 0;

        Conexion conexion =  new Conexion(Categorias.this);
        BD bd = conexion.conexion();
        SQLiteDatabase db =bd.getWritableDatabase();
        bd = conexion.conexion();

        if (db != null){
            try{
                Cursor cursorCategoriaHijos = db.rawQuery("SELECT id_categoria, nombre, slug FROM categoria_hijos WHERE id_padre='"+id_categoria+"' ", null);
                if (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        cantCategorias++;
                    }while (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToNext());
                }
                cursorCategoriaHijos.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error al leer datos de la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        conexion.closeConexion();
        bd.close();
        db.close();

        return cantCategorias;
    }

    public String[] obtenerNombresTabs(String id_categoria, int cantCategorias){
        String [] nombres = new String[cantCategorias];
        int cont = 0;
        Conexion conexion =  new Conexion(Categorias.this);
        BD bd = conexion.conexion();
        SQLiteDatabase db =bd.getWritableDatabase();

        if (db != null){
            try{
                Cursor cursorCategoriaHijos = db.rawQuery("SELECT id_categoria, nombre, slug FROM categoria_hijos WHERE id_padre='"+id_categoria+"' ", null);
                if (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        nombres[cont] = cursorCategoriaHijos.getString(1);
                        cont++;
                    }while (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToNext());
                }
                cursorCategoriaHijos.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error al leer datos de la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        conexion.closeConexion();
        bd.close();
        db.close();

        return nombres;
    }

    public String[] obtenerIdCategorias(String id_categoria, int cantCategorias){
        String [] idCategorias = new String[cantCategorias];
        int cont = 0;

        Conexion conexion =  new Conexion(Categorias.this);
        BD bd = conexion.conexion();
        SQLiteDatabase db =bd.getWritableDatabase();

        if (db != null){
            try{
                Cursor cursorCategoriaHijos = db.rawQuery("SELECT id_categoria, nombre, slug FROM categoria_hijos WHERE id_padre='"+id_categoria+"' ", null);
                if (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        idCategorias[cont] = cursorCategoriaHijos.getString(0);
                        cont++;
                    }while (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToNext());
                }
                cursorCategoriaHijos.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error al leer datos de la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        conexion.closeConexion();
        bd.close();
        db.close();

        return idCategorias;
    }

}
```

Esta es la función encargada de buscar los productos

```
public void llenarListaProductosCategorias(String id_categoria){
    ArrayList<Productos> arraydatos = new ArrayList<Productos>();
    Productos productos;

    Conexion conexion =  new Conexion(Categorias.this);
    BD bd = conexion.conexion();
    SQLiteDatabase db =bd.getWritableDatabase();

    if (db != null){
        Cursor category = db.rawQuery("SELECT nombre FROM categoria_hijos WHERE id_categoria="+id_categoria+"", null);
        if (category.moveToFirst()) {
            //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
            do {
                setTitle(category.getString(0));
            } while(category.moveToNext());
        }
        else
            setTitle("Categoría");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT p.id_producto, p.nombre_producto, p.descrip_corta_producto, p.nombre_img FROM productos as p, productos_cat_hijos as pc WHERE id_categoria_hijos='"+id_categoria+"' and pc.id_producto = p.id_producto", null);
        //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM productos_cat_hijos", null);
        try{
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                do {
                    productos = new Productos(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), null, c.getString(2), c.getString(3));
                    arraydatos.add(productos);
                } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No hay productos, Actualice la Aplicación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.close();

            final AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(this, arraydatos, getApplicationContext());
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListView listaProductos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_categorias_fragment);
                    if (listaProductos != null){
                        listaProductos.setAdapter(adapter);
                        listaProductos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { //hago clic en el elemento de la lista
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                                final int pos = position;
                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            TextView id_product = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_id_product);
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetallesProductos.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("ID_PRODUCT", id_product.getText().toString());
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                        }
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }).start();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("Error:", "No esta");
                    }
                    ProgressBar progressBar_videos = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_categorias);
                    progressBar_videos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }, 2000);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error:", "Error al leer datos de la base de datos 1");
        }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error de Conexion a la base de datos local, Vuelva actualizar la Aplicación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    conexion.closeConexion();
    bd.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Con esto controlo cual es el tabs seleccionado y vuelvo a llamar la función anterior que es la que se encarga de agregar los productos al listView y es cuando agrega la lista al tabs anterior al seleccionado

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
                new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        llenarListaProductosCategorias_1("216", tab);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    }
                }
        );
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano.
Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: Supongo que debes usar un view pager adapter para generar los tabs. Puedes añadir el codigo donde haces esto?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta y agregue lo que me pides, saludos

Answer (score -1):

En este caso el `ListView` debe agregarse al `Fragment`, archivo `fragment_categorias.xml`.

Por lo tanto tendrías que enviar los datos en el constructor del Fragment y llenar el ListView aquí:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categorias, container, false);

 AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(getActivity(), arraydatos, getApplicationContext());
ListView listaProductos = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista_categorias_fragment);
listaProductos.setAdapter(adapter);


    return rootView;
}
```

Por lo tanto `fragment_categorias.xml`  quedaría de esta forma:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ec.com.distribuidoresluisgonzalez.CategoriasFragment">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar_categorias"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -negativo, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicarlo.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero al quitar el ListView en esta linea ListView listaProductos = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista_categorias_fragment); dice que el no se ha iniciado el controlador, por si acaso yo no fui el que le di negativo a su respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @DeivisGonzálezGonzález especificamente cual es el mensaje?

Comment: Es decir cuando agrego esta linea ListView listaProductos = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista_categorias_fragment); la marca en rojo porque no existe el valor id lista_categorias_fragment , no se si me explique bien, saludos

Comment: @DeivisGonzálezGonzález no existe porque debes agregarlo en el layout del Fragment

Comment: Ahí es donde esta desde un principio, el layout de Fragment es fragment_categorias.xml